# Morphing a node of type A into type B, where both types are subclasses of C

Tags: c++, oop, tree

Situation: I have a simple language which allows the evaluation of arithmetic expressions. I construct an AST for a simple expression: `x + 8 * 9` (where `x` is some variable). The AST looks like this:

```
  AddExpression
  |           |
Var(x)   MultExpression
         |            |
      Const(8)     Const(9)
```

I have a generic `Expression` base class, from which `AddExpression`, `MultExpression`, `Var` and `Const` all derive. `MultExpression` looks somewhat like this, for example:

```
class MultExpression : public Expression
{
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> leftOperand;
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> rightOperand;

    bool canEvalCompileTime() const;
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> evalCompileTime() const;
};
```

`AddExpression` is roughly the same.

I would now like to perform basic constant folding; in this example, we'd like to transform the expression to `x + 72`. The most convenient way to do this would be to have the `MultExpression` transform into a `Const(72)` without the `AddExpression` knowing about it or taking part in it; however, even though `MultExpression` and `Const` both have `Expression` as their base class, I cannot morph one into another.

Instead, I have to go to the parent node instead (`AddExpression`) and involve it in the process; it has to verify that the optimization can indeed be performed, then ask `MultExpression` to perform it, then assign the resulting `Expression` pointer to its `rightOperand`:

```
if (rightOperand->canEvalCompileTime())
{
    rightOperand = rightOperand->evalCompileTime();
}
```

This works, but I feel like the first described approach would be cleaner. Is there a clean way to overcome the technical difficulty?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220046/is-it-possible-to-change-a-c-objects-class-after-instantiation

Comment: but it seems I would prefer just current implementation to keep things as simple as possible.